# Handle parents VisibleChanged event c#

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have created a C# usercontrol.

This usercontrol is hosted in a panel like so:

```
UserControlQuestion1 question1 = new UserControlQuestion1();
panel1.Controls.Add(question1);
panel1.Visible = true;
```

I want to add an event handler in my usercontrol to handle the panels VisibleChanged Event.

I have tried this which compiles correctly:

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        this.Parent.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Parent_VisibleChanged);
```

But when I run my program the this.Parent is null because it hasn't been added to the parent panel yet I guess

How can I do this?

Comment: Out of interest, what do you plan on doing when the `VisibleChanged` event fires? There may be a better way to solve your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Set your `VisibleChanged` event handler after you create the control

```
UserControlQuestion1 question1 = new UserControlQuestion1();
panel1.Controls.Add(question1);
question1.Parent.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(question1.Parent_VisibleChanged);
panel1.Visible = true;
```

OR

```
UserControlQuestion1 question1 = new UserControlQuestion1();
panel1.Controls.Add(question1);
panel1.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(question1.Parent_VisibleChanged);
panel1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Making use of what you have so far, you could create a "Register Event" function in your user control...

```
void RegisterEvent()
{
    this.Parent.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Parent_VisibleChanged);
}
```

which you can call after it has been added to the parent:

```
UserControlQuestion1 question1 = new UserControlQuestion1();
panel1.Controls.Add(question1);
question1.RegisterEvent();
panel1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try handling the `ParentChanged` event or override the `OnParentChanged` event raiser:

```
Control previousParent;
protected override void OnParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if(Parent != previousParent){
     if(Parent != null) Parent.VisibleChanged += Parent_VisibleChanged;
     if(previousParent != null) previousParent.VisibleChanged -= Parent_VisibleChanged;
     previousParent = Parent;
   }       
}
```

Note that with the code above, you don't need code to register the `Parent_VisibleChanged` in the `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: this is what I do. Why `parent == null` at `InitializeComponent` is that, creation of your control has not completed, so it is not yet added to the parent control's `Controls` collection.

Comment: @edokan my code doesn't care about `InitializeComponent`, it just listens to the `ParentChanged`, if it's changed and it's not null, then we can do something with it.